# The Analyzing part of the code don't work properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: txt.file]

I try reading data from shown file. After opening the file i need to count the rows on file and trying to split the data for further analyzes (to count total value of the inventory). I don't see where i have mistake, as it counts the rows, but seemingly dont do anything with the data itself (i have print there to see if it does anything).

```
def lueTiedosto(rows, Nimet): ##L08T5D1.txt
    Lue = input("Anna luettavan tiedoston nimi, nykyinen on ''.\n")
    print(f"Anna uusi nimi, enter säilyttää nykyisen: ", end='')
    Tiedosto = open(Lue, 'r', encoding="UTF-8")
    count = 0
    for Rivi in Tiedosto:
        if Rivi != "\n":
            count += 1
    print(f"Tiedosto {Lue} luettu, {count} riviä.")

    while (len(Rivi) > 0):
        
        Columns = Rivi.split(EROTIN)
        Item = VARASTO()
        Item.Tuote = Columns[0]
        Item.Hinta = Columns[2]
        Item.Maara = int(Columns[1])
        rows.append(Item)
        Rivi = Tiedosto.readline()
    print(Rivi)
    Tiedosto.close()
    return (rows, Nimet)
```

Comment: What value do you expect `Rivi` to have when your code executes `while (len(Rivi) > 0)`? Debug the code to see what value it actually has on each iteration.

Comment: After the `for Rivi in Tiedosto:` loop, the current file position is at the end of the file - calling `.readline()` on the file at that point will return nothing.  You'd need to either reopen the file, or use `.seek(0)` to rewind to the beginning.

Comment: Ty, it works after reopening the file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that after the first iteration on your file, the second iteration has nothing to iterate on. Moreover, the variable `Rivi` at the end of the first iteration is the empty string, so its length is 0; this means that the body of the while is not run.

You can refactor your code like this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Varasto:
    tuote: str
    hinta: float
    maara: int


def lueTiedosto(lue='varasto_tiedosto.txt', erotin=';'):  ##L08T5D1.txta
    while True:
        print(f"Anna luettavan tiedoston nimi, nykyinen on '{lue}'.")
        vastaus = input(f"Anna uusi nimi, enter säilyttää nykyisen:\n")
        if vastaus == '':
            break
        lue = vastaus

    count = 0
    stock = []
    with open(lue, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as tiedosto:
        for rivi in tiedosto:
            count += 1
            Columns = rivi.split(erotin)
            stock.append(Varasto(Columns[0], float(Columns[2]), int(Columns[1])))
            rivi = tiedosto.readline()
            print(rivi)
    print(f"Tiedosto {lue} luettu, {count} riviä.")

    return stock
```